# Can I combine these samples from the same poplulation?

Tags: sampling, dataset

I have gathered some data from university students. First time, I went in two classes and explained everything to students and asked them to participate. the two classes had the same incentives, but one of them had the additional class points incentive. These two classes didn't result in a large sample, so the third time I posted ads in Telegram channels that were about this university. the incentive was the same (no class points here though).

can I combine these samples? what are the things that I have to check before combining them??

Answer (score 0):

From experience with similar research situations, the answer is probably "yes"...but there are some things you can do to check.

First, when you do combine the data sets, create a new variable:  INCLASS.  Set this variable to 1 for the first group and 0 for the second group.  Now you can decide to use the data as one big data set (ie ignore the INCLASS variable), or you can do analyses in which you treat the two groups as related but distinct on a particular variable.

Because I don't know the structure your data (independent or dependent variables, etc), I can only make broad suggestions.  The first is to run a basic t-test on your "important" variables using the INCLASS variable as your grouping variable.  The more of these analyses that come up non-significant (p > alpha), the more justified you are in treating the two data sets as one large data set.  The second is to run regression models in which you use INCLASS as one of the predictors.  Let's say you want to predict y from x (data you have from each participant).  When you run the model, you would include x & INCLASS as predictors (and maybe even x * INCLASS).  If the INCLASS coefficient is not significant (or the interaction, too)...then you are justified in treating the data as one large data set.

Hope this is useful for your specific context.

Answer (score 0):

Pooling all data after checking that p-value of the "origin of sample"-variable is not significant will eventually lead to unreliable estimates of model's parameters. This is one of the many possible ways of committing **pseudo-replication** (*Hurlbert, 1984*).

To make full use of all data available, essentially two acceptable methods come to my mind :

1. First, it should be possible to calculate p-value of your model once for each sample, then combine all p-values using methods of meta-analysis (see Wikipedia article about meta-analysis for the complete methodology).
2. Second, if you wish to use most up-to-date statistical methods, treat your "origin of sample" variable as a random variable in a mixed-model. It is essentially the same as the first method but more refined and elegant, so that it can handle almost any type of experimental design, but also missing data as well as varying sample size natively.